# The relevant error-causing widget was: Scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
dashboardScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Positioned(child:
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Positioned(child: Column(
              //margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 30),
                children: persons.map((p) {
                  return personDetailCard(p);
                }).toList()
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        );
  }
```

I'm getting this error how can i solve it?

> The following assertion was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation:
> AnimationController#e4385(⏭ 1.000; paused), state:
> _AnimatedState#3a637): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4957 pos 16: 'child is!
> ParentDataElement': is not true.
>
> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we
> should provide substantially more information in this error message to
> help you determine and fix the underlying cause. In either case,
> please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    Scaffold
> file:///C:/Users/Saffar%20Khan/Documents/GitHub/flutter_app_afs/afs_mobile_flutter/lib/dashboard_Receiver.dart:190:12
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #2      ParentDataElement._applyParentData.applyParentDataToChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4957:16)
> #3      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4628:14)
> #4      ParentDataElement._applyParentData.applyParentDataToChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4958:15)
> #5      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4628:14)
> #6      ParentDataElement._applyParentData.applyParentDataToChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4958:15)

Answer (score 2):

As you're not using `Stack`, you must remove `Positioned` widget.

Try this tree:

```dart
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      //margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 30),
      children: persons.map((p) {
        return personDetailCard(p);
      }).toList(),
    ),
  ),
)
```